# How to treat an 'x' file extension as a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I want to rename a normal `.txt` file to `.my_extension`, not change its structure or anything.
Can I make python read that `.my_extension` as a `.txt` so it can read/write to it?

Comment: Python doesn't care at all about file extensions.  You can read/write from/to files with any extension.

Comment: @0x5453 You should post that as an answer, seems like it addresses the question pretty well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code will treat the custom extension file as a txt file and write to it.

```
File = open('File_Name.custom_extention', 'w').write('Text')
```

Same goes with reading. Python actually does not look at the file extension.
But if you'd try to write to a file with a file structure of an exec it probably won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

of course
actually python and almost every other language do not treat files by looking at the extension
they just do what you want
you can even have files with no extension and that's Ok
you can open a file just like this:

```
f = open('filename', 'mode')
```

to open a file
note that 'filename' should be the full name of file and the extension
somthing like 'myfile.myextension'

then write text into it like this

```
f.write('text to write in file')
```

see the list of modes in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can work with opening and closing files and writing ,reading etc..
with this line of code :

```
output_file = open("your_file_name",mode="r")
```

the `mode` can specify the mode that you open the file for example if you want only open a file for reading type `"r"` ,for writing type "w",for appending type "a".
*NOTE*:
After opening the file in python you must close it by the `close()` statement (this may cause data leaking).
ex:

```
output_file.close()
```